# Unexpected behaviour when using put with multidimensional Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A` defined as:

```
[[0, 0],
 [0, 0]]
```

I have a list `I` containing indices of `A`, for example `[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]`, and a list `v` with as many values as in `I`, for example `[1, 2, 3]`. I want to replace entries of `A` at indices contained in `I` with corresponding values stored in `v`. The expected result is therefore:

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3]]
```

I was expecting to be able to achieve this using `np.put`. I tried:

```
np.put(A, I, v)
```

However the value of `B` after running the line above is:

```
[[1., 3.],
 [0., 0.]]
```

Why did `put` behave this way and how can I achieve the result I was expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
I = np.array(I)
A[I[:, 0], I[:, 1]] = v

print(A)
```

Prints:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement @Arne's answer, the generic way to ravel the indices to match [`put`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html)'s format is to use [`ravel_multi_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index):

```
np.put(A, np.ravel_multi_index(np.array(I).T, A.shape), v)
```

Likewise, the generic indexing method would be:

```
A[tuple(zip(*I))] = v
```

Modified `A`:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

3D example:

```
A = np.zeros((2,3,4), dtype=int)
I = [(0,1,2), (1,1,1)]
v = [1, 2]

np.put(A, np.ravel_multi_index(np.array(I).T, A.shape), v)
# or
# A[tuple(zip(*I))] = v
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

[np.put()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) expects the index list to contain integers (not tuples), indexing the flat version of the target array. You could transform your indices to conform to this expectation:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0],
              [0, 0]])
I = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
v = [1, 2, 3]

n_cols = A.shape[1]
I_flat = [n_cols * i + j for i, j in I]

np.put(A, I_flat, v)
print(A)
```

Then the output is as expected:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
```